# Flask app with AJAX post gives 404 (NOT FOUND)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm new to this and making a small Flask app.

I've gone through everything similar I can find online, but I still can't get a minimal working example of passing data from client-side to server-side using AJAX.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
  $('a#test_function').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
          url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/test',
          data: JSON.stringify({ "value":'asdf' }),
          type: 'POST'
          success: function(response) {
               console.log(response);
          },
          error: function(error) {
               console.log(error);
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>

<h1>jQuery Example</h1>
<a href=# id=test_function>get string</a>
```

And here is the .py file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash, jsonify, json

# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__)

# Load default config and override config from an environment variable
app.config.update(
DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'mydb.db'),
DEBUG=True,
SECRET_KEY='something',
SERVER_NAME='http://localhost:5000'
)

@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    flash('Welcome!')
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    vars = request.data
    return ', '.join([str(i) for i in vars])
```

When I run the server and attempt to run the post request, I get the following error:

```
 POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/test 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the entire `.py` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To POST JSON data via XHR to Flask the method I use is to set the `Content-Type` heading to `"application/json"`. Then you can access this within Flask from the `request.data` object. I cleaned up a couple typos as well.

Javascript/HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};

    $(function() {
        $('a#test_function').bind('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/test",
                data: JSON.stringify({"key": "value"}),
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(response, error) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<h1>jQuery Example</h1>
<a href="#" id="test_function">get string</a>
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    vars = request.data
    return ', '.join([str(i) for i in vars])
```

Comment: Hmm...just made an edit because I was referencing a blueprint in my local environment (changed `@main.route` to `@app.route`. If that doesn't address the issue please post your full HTML as well. Thanks!

Comment: Also - this example works on my machine in Dev. When I click the "get string" link i can see a result post to the Javascript console. Another recommendation for Flask is to use lots of print statements in your Python (similar to console.log in javascript) and you can see that output in terminal when you're running the server locally.

Comment: Perfect this seems to work now, must be the header. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. I remember pulling my hair out over this issue when I first started with Flask XHR which is why I jumped on it ;) Also, since I'm working to build my Stack Overflow reputation it would be a big help if you could accept my answer. Thanks!